# onPageLoad is not working properly in Firefox Extension Development

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am new to Firefox Extension Development and doing my 1st program.
Simply I needed to pop up a alert once it loaded the page.
My code was like this:

```
var myExtension = {  
init: function() {    
    if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);  
},  
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) { 
alert("Loaded");  
}
}  
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){  
window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
myExtension.init();    
},false);
```

But I am getting the alert box for couple of times.
Then I found about "#document" and then I added a IF condition:

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) { 
    if (aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName == '#document')  {
    alert("Loaded");  
    }
}
```

Unfortunately still I am getting the same.
Please advise me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an iframe issue. To filter out iframes:

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) { 
    let ot=aEvent.originalTarget;
    if (ot.nodeName == '#document' && !ot.defaultView.frameElement)  {
    alert("Loaded");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find description of several methods for intercepting page loads from Firefox addon at MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

Choosing right solution depends on what you want to achieve.

- Do you want to do something when some specific page loads?
- Do you want to do something when any page loads?
- Do you need to do it when whole page loads (onload), when the
  document is ready (ondomready) or when page displayed in Firefox
  changes, e.g. when switching or opening tabs (this requires completly
  different approach)?